# Removing class dependency in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a class that creates Custom Selectboxes. its working fine and I want this class to be more generic.
These Selectboxes have also "onchange" Event listener.

Now before calling the onchange method I want to perfom some complex tests. And these tests are defined in another class.

To achive the genericity I don't want that I have to initilize new classes within the SelectBox class.
What should be the bestway to solve this problem? And the Data which is required to perfom tests is within SelectBox class.

Thanks

Comment: We can't help you unless you actually show us the code - simply describing it usually isn't specific enough in cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if those functions don't depend on new-initialized-objects-specific-variables, then you can just make those functions into public static ones

```
var AnotherClass = (function(){
  // this is a public static method
  this.complexTask = function(){ alert('I am too complex for my shirt'); }

  return function(){
    // initialization-dependent-stuff
  }
})();

var SelectBoxes = (function(){
   return function(){
      this.onChange = function(){
         AnotherClass.complexTask();
      }
   }
});
```

by doing this, you don't have to initialize anything, plus you get to use your functions the way you want.

Alternatively, if you can't use public static methods, then you should consider passing a instance of that class as a parameter, although the method above is preffered